# Doctrine MySQL, how to make andWhere optional with getRepository()

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a simple query on app controller to generate a list view. I need to add optional andWhere if a user has provided a search term.

This is my query that works with hardcoded search term:

```
$devSearch = '%youtube%';

$postsList = $em->getRepository('\\App\\Entity\\' . $model)
  ->createQueryBuilder('p')
  ->where($queryOpts['where'])
  ->andWhere('p.link LIKE :search')
  ->setParameter('search', $devSearch)
  ->setMaxResults($postPayload)
  ->setFirstResult($offset)
  ->getQuery()
  ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

$totalItems = count($postsList);
```

I need to make this part optional:

```
  ->andWhere('p.link LIKE :search')
  ->setParameter('search', $devSearch)
```

Is there any straight-forward way to do it?

I thought I should be able to do this, but it fails:

```
$postsList = $em->getRepository('\\App\\Entity\\' . $model);

$postsList
  ->createQueryBuilder('p')
  ->where($queryOpts['where']);

if($devSearch) {
  $postsList
    ->andWhere('p.link LIKE :search')
    ->setParameter('search', $devSearch)
}

$postsList
  ->setMaxResults($postPayload)
  ->setFirstResult($offset)
  ->getQuery()
  ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Comment: how does it fail ? syntax error as you miss a ';'

Comment: Even with semicolon it fails with error:



Message: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder given

Answer (score -1):

this can be written like this

```
$x = $em->getRepository('\\App\\Entity\\' . $model)
  ->createQueryBuilder('p')
  ->where($queryOpts['where']);

if (xxxxx)
  $x->andWhere('p.link LIKE :search')
  ->setParameter('search', $devSearch)
  
$results = $x->setMaxResults($postPayload)
  ->setFirstResult($offset)
  ->getQuery()
  ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Comment: Even with semicolon it fails with error: Message: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder given

Comment: it means that your code didnt work before adding the if statement :) Try adding lines one by one next time. instead of testing all at once.

Comment: this thread may have the answer you need https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/doctrine-setmaxresult-fonctionnant-bizarrement